# AWS EC2 Autoscaling Average CPU utilization v.s. Grafana CPU utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage, grafana, autoscaling

We want to use AWS predictive scaling to forecast the load and CPU so this will certainly help us move away from manually launching instances based on load. We created new scaling plan by choosing EC2 Autoscaling group and enabling predictive scaling(forecast only for now). But we noticed that the CPU graph on Grafana is different from AWS Average CPU utilization. Grafana is getting alerts from elasticsearch which gets logs directly from services running in ec2. I am not sure why they don't show the same percentage of CPU Utilization and am wondering why AWS CPU Utilization is lower than the CPU shows on Grafana? If so can autoscaling scales the instances correctly?
[AWS Autoscaling group Average CPU utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ7xj.png)

[Grafana Averge CPU graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x6IM.png)

Answer (score 0):

AWS has its own method of computing CPU Util which is based on "EC2 compute units" so it is possible that value will differ when compared to another way of calculating the same metrics.